# How to add hyphenation support for custom command?

Tags: macros, hyphenation

Given the following custom commands:

```
\newcommand{\topic}[1]{#1\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{\textsf{\topic{#1}}}
```

which is used for Java classes with full package name, like:

```
\class{org.openscience.cdk.layout.StructureDiagramGenerator}
```

With the current command definition, the class name will not be hyphenated at the periods. How can I change my \newcommand{} to have LaTeX hyphenate the class at periods?

I am using the \class{} inside \caption{} methods which seems to invalidate some solutions.

Comment: Can you please clarify where the `\topic` command comes from? (It would be even better if you could provide a minimal working expample.)

Comment: Oops. Thanx for the ping. Added now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would be inclined to use the `url` package for this task. (It provides flexible options for linebreaking of such things, not only URLs.) Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\printtopic{\urlstyle{sf}}
\newcommand{\topic}[1]{\protect\printtopic{#1}\index{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\class}[1]{\topic{#1}}
\begin{document}
text foo bar baz hello
\class{org.openscience.cdk.layout.StructureDiagramGenerator}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This set up gives me: "\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument."

Comment: The problem seems to be that I use the \class{} command in a \caption{}... is there a solution to that?

Comment: @Egon: Can you please specify where the error shows up? I have no problem compiling Will's code.

Comment: Put the class{} in a figure \caption{}...

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for such cases (look up "fragile commands" in a LaTeX reference to explain all this). Now fixed above.

Comment: Thanx, that works!

Comment: @Egon: Sorry, I don't know what was wrong with me when I wrote that comment.

Comment: I've adapted this solution, but I find that there are cases where breaking at the period isn't good enough; sometimes I really do need to break in the middle of one of the package name compononents, such as "openscience" in the example above. Is there some way to use a discretionary hyphen-like hint in concert with `url`?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do it will be next to impossible to get an acceptable typesetting with all variants of class names. One could use an approach where you can use a semi-manual approach as shown in the example below (last example).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\overfullrule=0.5pt
\parskip=20pt
Using \textbackslash url, it will remove all spaces the colon will be placed at end of section, whereas a common convention is to move it at the next line

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{1.65in}
\url{org.openscience.cdk.layout.StructureDiagramGenerator}
\end{minipage}}



\gdef\classformatter#1{
    \hyphenpenalty=-200
    \textsf{#1}
}

It is impossible for \TeX to hyphenate the next example, as the fist word of a paragraph is never hyphenated and this is treated as one long word (\TeX\ is probably thinking it is just a long abbreviation).

\begin{minipage}{1.65in}
\classformatter{org.openscience.cdk.organizationlayout.StructureDiagramGenerator}
\end{minipage}


If you type a space at the point you want to allow a break \TeX\ will attempt to hyphenate,

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{1.65in}
\classformatter{org.openscience.cdk .organizationlayout .StructureDiagramGenerator}
\end{minipage}}

You will never avoid a little bit of hand manipulation, allow a break now and then;

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{1.65in}
\classformatter{org.openscience.cdk\\ .organizationlayout .StructureDiagramGenerator}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```